# Svelte: how to pass `on:` event to a child component

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to create a component that will handle `on:click`, but without exporting an `handleClick` function; this is how it works right now

`button.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let handleClick: ((e: MouseEvent) => void ) | undefined = undefined
</script>
<button on:click={handleClick}>
  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

`app.svelte`:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import Button from '$lib/button/button.svelte'
</script>
<Button handleClick={() => console.log('click!')}>
  Click me!
</button>
```

How to change the Button element to use `on:click` directly in the app component?

`app.svelte`:

```html
<Button on:click={handleClick}>
  <slot></slot>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [Svelte documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname):

> If the `on:` directive is used without a value, the component will forward the event, meaning that a consumer of the component can listen for it.

So you should be able to do this in `button.svelte`:

```html
<button on:click>
  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

And then this should work in `app.svelte`:

```html
<script>
import Button from './button.svelte';

const handleClick = (event) => {
  // …
};
</script>

<Button on:click={handleClick}>
  Foo
</Button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Will be more patient during reading the docs next time